# Play youtube video from URL in android

Tags: android

I want to play youtube video in my application. I am getting video URL from SAX Parsing. My question is how to play video from URL in VideoView, not in Webview or Browser.

I tried this code :

```
Intent lVideoIntent = new Intent(null, Uri.parse("VIDEO URL"));
startActivity(lVideoIntent);
```

It is displaying one popup screen with 'Internet' and 'YouTube' options. I want to play the video directly in youtube.

Please let me know your thoughts. Any code or any example is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your help. I checked this. But I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code for direct play in `Youtube` application.

```
    Intent videoClient = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            videoClient.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwSdmxyayx0&amp;feature=youtube_gdata"));//you can try here your own video url
            videoClient.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity");
            try{
                startActivity(videoClient);
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException excp){
                try{
                    videoClient.setClassName("com.google.android.youtube", "com.google.android.youtube.WatchActivity");
                     startActivity(videoClient);
                }catch(ActivityNotFoundException exc){
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi Herry. Suppose this is the link of video URL : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwSdmxyayx0&amp;feature=youtube_gdata... How to write this in Uri.parse("") Can you please show me the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
String videoUrl = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxLG2wtE7TM"

//split video url and get value of v ie cxLG2wtE7TM

String videoId = "cxLG2wtE7TM";
String action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW;
Uri uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + videoId);
Intent videoIntent = new Intent(action, uri);
startActivity(videoIntent);
```

Comment: Will this compile ok? I see that the String videoId is literal and not in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse("video url"));
 VideoActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

**It is displaying one popup screen with 'Internet' and 'YouTube'**

because the ACTION_VIEW intent is written both in default browser and Youtube application. that's why whenever it catches the URL the Browser opens and whenever the Youtube URL is opened Both the browser and Youtube app.

**I want to play the video directly in youtube**

Take the embed link of Youtube video and set intent it will play the video.

ex:-`http://www.youtube.com/embed/srMFb6zpx2Y`