# Android Stream Video from url

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Lets say I have a url (it is not specific it will be a youtube link)

On click of the thumbnail/button I want to fire a pop up sorts that there is in android asking  which player to use.

I know there are a lot of articles on it but I cannot get it working.

I tried out this:

```
package com.example.videotry;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.imageButton1) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setType("video/*");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/embed/PW_88sL_2dA?feature=oembed" ));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
    }



}

}
```

but it throws an error:

```
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at com.example.videotry.Play.onClick(Play.java:18)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14110)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-22 15:08:00.680: E/AndroidRuntime(8163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's not about the video format. I tried different formats. 
I am using android 4.0

I have also tried ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`

instead

`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);`

I think it can helps you: [Play youtube video from URL in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407498/play-youtube-video-from-url-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the constructor for Intent class,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```